# Spring Context doesn't seem to recognize a Bean when creating it with stereotype annotations. Throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-bean, spring-context

I'm following a book to learn some modules of the Spring ecosystem. Currently trying to create beans using stereotype annotations.
I've written a simple Java class and marked it as a component:

```
package main.parrot;
@Component
public class Parrot {
  private String name;
  // getters and setters //
}
```

I then created a @Configuration class which scans for the Parrot component:

```
package main;
//imports
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "parrot")
public class ProjectConfig{}
```

In my main method I am creating a spring context using the configuration above, and I'm trying to access the bean Parrot:

```
package main;
//imports//
public class Main{
  public static void main(String...args){
    var context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ProjectConfig.class);
    var p = context.getBean(Parrot.class);
  }
}
```

The line of code in which I attempt to get the Parrot bean throws the following exception:
**NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'main.parrot.Parrot' available**

I just don't understand why this configuration wouldn't find the Parrot bean. If someone could help me clarify the issue I would be extremely grateful.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `basePackages` to include the complete package name:

```java
package main;
//imports
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "main.parrot")
public class ProjectConfig{}
```

Comment: I see, thank you very much. I had tried that but I get a huge error if I do that. Looks like that's just because the class files are unsupported by the version of spring I'm using though so I can easily fix that.
Thanks again!